# Update multiple subdocument without exact sub document level condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I have collection with the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cbf9cd75de3ee9057b23c7"),
    "title" : "Abc",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "_id" : "",
            "message" : "",
            "active" : 1,
            "status" : 1,
        },
        {
            "_id" : "",
            "message" : "",
            "active" : 0,
            "status" : 1,
        },
        {
            "_id" : "",
            "message" : "",
            "active" : 1,
            "status" : 1,

        }
    ],

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553744ae75de3eb9128b4568"),
    "title" : "Jhon",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "_id" : "",
            "message" : "",
            "active" : 1,
            "status" : 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update all **status of comments** as **0** where **comments.active=1**. I tried to solve it as below, but only first record of the comments is updated. Please help me..

```
db.comments.update({'comments.active':1},{$set:{'comments.$.status':0}})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289565/multi-subdocument-update-in-mongo-subdocument-arrays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per this issue [`New operator to update all matching items in an array`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243), currently there is no operation to do that in mongodb. Feel so sad, this issue lasts for 6 years.

There could be one work around in mongo shell as below.

```
> db.comments
    .find({})
    .forEach(function(doc) { 
                        doc.comments.map(function(c) {
                                if (c.active == 1) {
                                    c.status = 0;
                                 }
                        }); 
                        db.comments.update(
                                      {_id: doc._id}, 
                                      {$set: {comments: doc.comments}});
     });
```